# Getting HTTP error 500 with Slim Framework (php)

Tags: php, .htaccess, slim

I am getting HTTP error 500 when using the Slim framework.

I have the index.php of Slim Framework in /api/v1/:

```
<?php

require '../../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new Slim\App();

$app->get('/auth2', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    $response->write("Welcome to Slim!");
    return $response;
});

$app->run();
```

In the same folder I have my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

But when I go to /api/v1/auth2 the page doesn't load. I only get a HTTP error 500. Have I misconfigured Slim?

Comment: Check your error-log.

Comment: did my answer helped you ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put this code at the top of the page you are trying to load.

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

This will print you the errors if your functions are not with `@`.

Comment: Yep, it helped me troubleshoot. Thanks!